# Khatri product of matrices using np.tensordot

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor, scikit-tensor

I'm trying to decompose a Tensor (m, n, o) into matrices A(m, r), B (n, r) and C (k, r). This is known as PARAFAC decomposition. [Tensorly](https://tensorly.github.io/) already does this kind of a decomposition.

An important step is to multiply A, B, and C to get a tensor of shape (m, n, o).

Tensorly does this as follows:

```
def kt_to_tensor(A, B, C):
    factors = [A, B, C]
    for r in range(factors[0].shape[1]):
        vecs = np.ix_(*[u[:, r] for u in factors])
        if r:
            res += reduce(np.multiply, vecs)
        else:
            res = reduce(np.multiply, vecs)
    return res
```

However, the package I'm using (Autograd) does not support `np.ix_` operations. I thus wrote a simpler definition as follows:

```
def new_kt_to_tensor(A, B, C):
    m, n, o = A.shape[0], B.shape[0], C.shape[0]
    out = np.zeros((m, n, o))
    k_max = A.shape[1]
    for alpha in range(0, m):
        for beta in range(0, n):
            for delta in range(0, o):
                for k in range(0, k_max):
                    out[alpha, beta, delta]=out[alpha, beta, delta]+ A[alpha, k]*B[beta, k]*C[delta, k]
    return out
```

However, it turns out that this implementation also has some aspects that autograd does not support. However, autograd does support `np.tensordot`.

I was wondering how to use `np.tensordot` to obtain this multiplication. I think that Tensorflow's `tf.tensordot` would also have a similar functionality.

Intended solution should be something like:

```
def tensordot_multplication(A, B, C):
    """
    use np.tensordot
    """
```

Comment: I'm surprised by your `ix_` comment.  That's been part of numpy for a long time.  The `reduce` may require an import in PY3.

Comment: @hpaulj : Numpy does support these. However, Autograd does not allow using .ix_ for computing gradient. See: https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/issues/210

Comment: `ix_` just does the kind of dimension expansion that Divakar's first approach does.  The `reduce` applies the multiplication part.

Comment: Okay. Just that Autograd currently does not support ix_

Comment: I looked at `Autograd`. Apparently it parses the numpy code, and does it's own 'symbolic' gradient.  It's not actually running your function.  `ix_` is in a file called `np.lib.index_tricks` and provides a variety of indexing shortcuts, but no new functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think `np.tensordot` would help you here, as it needs to *spread-out* the axes that don't participate in sum-reductions, as we have the alignment requirement of keeping the last axis aligned between the three inputs while performing multiplication. Thus, with `tensordot`, you would need extra processing and have more memory requirements there.

I would suggest two methods - One with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and another with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).

**Approach #1 :** With `broadcasting` -

```
(A[:,None,None,:]*B[:,None,:]*C).sum(-1)
```

Explanation :

- Extend `A` to `4D`, by introducing new axes at `axis=(1,2)` with None/np.newaxis.
- Similarly extend `B` to `3D`, by introducing new axis at `axis=(1)`.
- Keep `C` as it is and perform elementwise multiplications resulting in a `4D` array.
- Finally, the sum-reduction comes in along the last axis of the `4D` array.

Schematically put -

```
A        : m        r
B        :    n     r
C        :       k  r

=> A*B*C : m  n  k  r
=> out   : m  n  k    # (sum-reduction along last axis)
```

**Approach #2 :** With `np.einsum` -

```
np.einsum('il,jl,kl->ijk',A,B,C)
```

The idea is the same here as with the previous `broadcasting` one, but with string notations helping us out in conveying the axes info in a more concise manner.

`Broadcasting` is surely available on `tensorflow` as it has tools to [`expand dimensions`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims), whereas `np.einsum` is probably not.

Comment: Thanks! This is excellent! It would be great if you could add a couple of lines explaining each of the solutions!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It really makes it very helpful now!

Answer (score 1):

The code you refer to isn't actually how TensorLy implements it but simply an alternative implementation given in the doc.

The [actual code](https://tensorly.github.io/stable/_modules/tensorly/kruskal.html#kruskal_to_tensor) used in TensorLy is:

```
def kruskal_to_tensor(factors):
    shape = [factor.shape[0] for factor in factors]
    full_tensor = np.dot(factors[0], khatri_rao(factors[1:]).T)
    return fold(full_tensor, 0, shape)
```

where the [khatri_rao](https://tensorly.github.io/stable/_modules/tensorly/tenalg/_khatri_rao.html#khatri_rao) is implemented using numpy.einsum in a way that generalizes what Divakar suggested.